# Rails console is not showing attribute when called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
>> Reply.first
=> #< Reply id: 1, body: "line1\r\n\r\nline2\r\n" >
```

But when I do

```
>> Reply.first.body
=> "line1"
```

Its breaking a few of my tests where they are looking for :

```
assert_difference 'Reply.where(:body => "line1\r\n\r\nline2").count' do
```

How can my tests be reassured there are line breaks?

Comment: Seems like you have a custom "getter" for `body`

Comment: Is this using `ActionMailer`, or some other mail gem?

Comment: Try to fetch the attribute with `Reply.first[:body]`

Comment: Wow Stefan that is right on. I can't *believe* I overlooked that. It does have a custom getter. And you are a genius my friend.

Comment: Great :) I've posted it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a custom getter, something like:

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  def body
    "foo"
  end
end

reply = Reply.new(body: "bar")
#=> #<Reply id:nil, body: "bar" created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

reply.body
#=> "foo"
```

In that case, you can fetch the raw attribute using `Model[:attribute_name]`:

```
reply[:body]
#=> "bar"
```

Comment: This oddly doesn't work.. `Reply.where(body: Reply.first[:body])`

Comment: What about `Reply.where(body: "line1\r\n\r\nline2\r\n")`?

Comment: Indeed, could you inspect the query and/or the database entry?

Comment: Reply.first.body.inspect => `"\"line1\""`. Then if I do Reply.first[:body].inspect => `"\"line1\\r\\n\\r\\nline2\\r\\n\""` . Neither of which are capabable of finding the object by its body.

Answer (score 0):

Change the snytax a little bit when you have backslash's

```
assert_difference 'Reply.where("body = 'line1\r\n\r\nline2\r\n'").count' do
```